# what's the line meaning in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function bind( obj, type, fn ) {
    if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
        obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
        obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
        obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    } else
        obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
```

i am new to javascript, the above code is from the internet. i don't understand the above function well, expect someone can explain it to me. thank you, why it declare three argument(obj, type, fn).  `obj['e'+type+fn]` what's this line meaning.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use jQuery instead some poorly-documented code.

Comment: Do not use this code. It is an extremely poor, buggy, leaky implementation of cross-browser event handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function accepts three parameters:

1. An object (specifically, a DOM node) that it will set an event handler on
2. The event which will have the handler attached to it (e.g. "click")
3. A function which is the event handler

It then creates two "helper" functions and uses them to assign the event handler:

```
obj['e'+type+fn] = fn; // helper #1
obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );} // helper #2
obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] ); // assigns event handler
```

The lines with the `obj[something]` syntax are simply accessing (getting/setting) a member of `obj` whose name is variable. For example, this:

```
var name = "alert";
window[name]();
```

does the same thing as this:

```
window.alert();
```

However, in the first case you have the value of `name` coming from a variable instead of being hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

`obj['e'+type+fn]` accesses the attribute of `obj` with the name `'e' + type + fn`.

With `type='abc'` and `fn='foo'`, it would access `obj.eabcfoo`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, there is an equivalence between objects and hash sets. Thus, saying `obj['abc']=123;` is equivalent to `obj.abc=123`. By using the hash set notation, you can build your property names dynamically - in this case by concatenating `'e'` with the values of `type` and `fn`.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to attach events to objects dynamically.

For example to assign `click` event to some element:

```
var oDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
bind(oDiv, "click", MyClickHandler);
```

This will bind the `click` event of element with ID `myDiv` and execute function called `MyClickHandler` when that element is clicked.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sDwvP/

These days such things are considered "old school" or obsolete, you better use full scale library like jQuery.